# Recursive CTE...dealing with nested parent/children records

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have the following records:

[image]

My goal is to check the SUM of the children for each parent and make sure it is 1 (or 100%).

In the example above, you have a first parent:

12043

It has 2 children:

12484 & 12485

Child (now parent) 12484 has child 12486. The child here (12486) has a percentage of 0.6 (which is NOT 100%). This is NOT OK.

Child (now parent) 12485 has child 12487. The child here (12487) has a percentage of 1 (or 100%). This is OK.

I need to sum the percentages of each nested children and get that value because it doesn't sum up to 100%, then I have to display a message. I'm having a hard time coming up with a query for this. Can someone give me a hand?

This is what I tried and I'm getting the "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion." error message.

```
  with  cte
          as (select  cp.parent_payee_id,
                      cp.payee_id,
                      cp.payee_pct,
                      0 as level
              from    dbo.tp_contract_payee cp
              where   cp.participant_id = 12067
                      and cp.payee_id = cp.parent_payee_id
              union all
              select  cp.parent_payee_id,
                      cp.payee_id,
                      cp.payee_pct,
                      c.level + 1 as level
              from    dbo.tp_contract_payee cp
              inner join cte c
              on      cp.parent_payee_id = c.payee_id
              where   cp.participant_id = 12067
             )
    select  *
    from    cte
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe something like the following should work:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        parent_payee_id as parent,
        payee_id as child,
        payee_pct
        1 as depth,
        parent_payee_id + '>' + payee_id as path
    FROM
        table
    WHERE
        --top most node
        parent_payee_id = 12043 
        AND payee_id <> parent_payee_id --prevent endless recursion

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        table.parent_payee_id as parent,
        table.payee_id as child,
        table.payee_pct,
        recCTE.depth + 1 as Depth,
        recCTE.path + '>' + table.payee_id as path
    FROM
        recCTE
        INNER JOIN table ON
            recCTE.child = table.parent_payee_id AND
            recCTE.child <> table.payee_id --again prevent records where parent is child
    Where depth < 15 --prevent endless cycles
)

SELECT DISTINCT parent
FROM recCTE
GROUP BY parent
HAVING sum(payee_pct) <> 1;
```

This differs from yours mostly in the `WHERE` statements on both the Recursive Seed (query before UNION) and the recursive term (query after UNION). I believe yours is too restrictive, especially in the recursive term since you want to allow records that are children of 12067 through, but then you only allow 12067 as the parent id to pull in.

Here, though, we pull every descendant of 12043 (from your example table) and it's payee_pct. Then we analyze each parent in the final SELECT and the sum of all it's payee_pcts, which are essentially that parent's first childrens sum(payee_pct). If any of them are not a total of 1, then we display the parent in the output.

At any rate, between your query and mine, I would imagine this is pretty close to the requirements, so it should be tweaks to get you exactly where you need to be if this doesn't do the trick.